# What is a "Locked Topic" on Google Product Forums?

Tags: google-product-forums

Visiting the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome), I see some topics that are marked as **Locked**. There is a small gray padlock icon to the right of the title. Here’s an example: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/mu6_a2z9iJ0. I assume this means no new replies are allowed, but I cannot verify this assumption, nor can I seem to find any information about what a Locked Topic actually is.

I tried searching the Google Product Forums about this, but unfortunately haven’t found any search results pertaining to the forum itself. (Like a "meta" forum for questions *about* the forum).

Can anyone point me to some official Google documentation on the inner-workings of Google Product Forums, specifically on **Locked Topics**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "locked" topic [simply  means that a topic can no longer be replied to/answered](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/H0W9EV5x2fo).

"Locking" a topic is a Moderator action.

From [Groups Help: Permissions](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465496), "Lock Topics" is a permission that Moderators have:

> **Lock Topics**
>   A person with this permission can lock or unlock a topic.

This suggests that it's a policy decision by the Moderators of the Product Forums. You'd need to check with them for what their criteria are. From what I can see, they seem to lock conversations that are old and don't have recent replies, resolved questions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it's not entirely locked, but locked for new replies. 
Not a manual action, but automatic. 
If you use the old forum interface, you'd see this notice at the top: 
[image]

If the topic was locked (via manual action; either locked or duplicated to another topic), you'd see red lock instead (only on the old forum interface).

There is an official meta-forum for Google product forums, just not a dedicated one:

In https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1649687, open the 'Help forum' link in the top right, and end up in https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/apps/google-groups-for-business, which, granted, can be misleading.

Also see [Google Groups: Difference between lock reply and lock topic.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/YwXSsHDfq-0)